# How to work with textual formats in otherwise procedural code?

Tags: c#, text, dsl, declarative

This question sounds trivial but let me explain my scenario.

I am working in an object oriented programming language (C#) and most of the actual execution code is **procedural**, i.e. series of statements, sometimes branches and loops. Fairly standard.

Now I am presented with a task to deal with a textual format ([PGN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation), but it could be anything other like [VCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) or some custom format). At least for me, the "standard" way to work with it would be to use a mix of:

- regular expressions
- if / switch statements
- for-loops
- storing regexp matches into some custom structure and / or outputting it to some result format

However, I don't like this procedural approach at all - regular expressions are prone to errors, the code is usually quite hard to understand and debug, it usually tends to have quite a high cyclomatic complexity etc.

Simply put, I'd like it to be **declarative** but I don't know what tools or libraries to use.

I remember that when I saw demos of the **"M" language** I thought that that was exactly I was looking for. There was a simple way to declare syntax of my textual format, the tool would then automatically parse input string into an in-memory representation of the textual DSL, I think that it was also possible to transform the format into another etc.

I have been also in touch with the people behind **[JetBrains MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/)** which is another tool for working with DSLs but my scenario doesn't seem to be a perfect match for what they are trying to provide.

So if anyone has any idea about how to elegantly deal with textual formats in otherwise procedural code base, I'd be happy to learn about the options.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my open source project [meta#](http://metasharp.codeplex.com). I think it sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks nice. What's the state of the project? From the roadmap (http://metasharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap&referringTitle=Home) it seems that it is quite early in the development.

Comment: The pattern matching capabilities are robust. The msbuild task that supports build-time transformation is also good. The ancillary features such as IDE integration is poor. The grammar language sits on top of a general purpose language which is incomplete. 

But the core scenarios are stable and effective, for example: http://justinmchase.com/2011/10/05/martin-fowlers-state-machine-in-meta/

There are some users. What it needs is some more contributors. There is a nuget package you can use to try it out immediately.